# Mat Dialog Scroll to top spcifically after some event

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am working on Angular 11. using Mat-dialog, I need to scroll to top in dialog container from my handle error function. I tried varios methods but not scrolling up, even there is no error on console.

I tried window.scroll, scrollTo, scrollToView(true) & few other methods but nothing working. Can't share the code due to security reasons.
I also tried to focus on element but that is also not working.